# Removable singularity theorems for manifolds

Tags: riemann-surfaces

All the theorems on removable singularities are for functions defined on open domains $\Omega \in \mathbb{C}$. But what are the corresponding theorems for functions defined on Riemann surfaces? How do they differ and are there any extra issues we need to take into account?

Comment: Locally any Riemann surface is (biholomorphic to) an open domain in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, for Riemann Surfaces, the following version of Riemann's Removable Singularity Theorem holds:

> **Theorem:***Let $X$ be a Riemann surface, and $f:X-\{p\}\to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function. If $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $p$, then $f$ extends uniquely to a holomorphic function $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$.*

This is proven, as the comment suggests, by working some some coordiante disc around $p$ and applying the usual Riemann's Theorem.

A generalization of this to higher-dimensional manifolds has several possible forms. The most general that I know of is [Hartog's Extension Theorem](http://www.math.ens.fr/~merker/Exposes/2007/shrunk-lille-8-mars-2007.pdf). This is a much deeper result, and has many implications. It's algebraic analogue is every useful in algebraic geometry as well.